# How can I get bundle of an entity from type and id?

Tags: 7, entities

I need to identify `bundle` of an entity from its `type` and `id`.

For example, if the `type` is 'node' and `id` is 7, I may get 'page' as `bundle`.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Use `entity_load` to load the entity as mentioned by @Nikhil.

Then use [entity_extract_ids](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_extract_ids/7), to extract the bundle. Example:

```
$entity = entity_load('node', array('7'));

list(, , $bundle) = entity_extract_ids('node', $entity);

echo "Bundle name is : " . $bundle;
```

The function `entity_extract_ids` returns a numerically indexed array (not a hash table) containing the elements:

- 0: Primary ID of the entity.
- 1: Revision ID of the entity, or NULL if $entity_type is not
  versioned.
- 2: Bundle name of the entity, or NULL if $entity_type has no bundles.

where, `0`, `1`, and `2` are array indices. However, the approach used by core and contrib modules is to use the `list()` function.

Comment: I think it is not good to depend on array numeric index.

Comment: @Junaid That index is predictable so it's fine. This is how Drupal core handles this task. If the 'magic number' bothers you just use language features: `list($id, $vid, $bundle) = entity_extract_ids($entity_type, $entity);`

Comment: @Junaid You can depend on the numeric index, when you are sure they won't change. See the edit for the explanation of why I used the numeric index. It is because the API function is designed that way. Also, the solution is not dependent of the entity module ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Here is <strike>the cleanest</strike> one that I got from Organic groups module code.

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity_id);
$bundle = $wrapper->getBundle();
```

For example I can call it like:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', 1);
$bundle = $wrapper->getBundle();
```

Edit:
As @Clive pointed out, above method depends on entity module.

Here is another method that does not depend on any extra module. It is explained here https://forrst.com/posts/Get_the_bundle_of_a_Drupal_7_entity-0xW

Copy pasting that method:

```
function _entity_get_bundle($entity, $entity_type) {
  $info = entity_get_info($entity_type);
  if (empty($info['entity keys']['bundle'])) {
    return $entity_type;
  } else {
    return $entity->{$info['entity keys']['bundle']};
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `$group_type, $gid` ? and whats the value in `$bundle ` ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to use proper parameter names. It is corrected now.

Comment: You can do the same for `entity_load`, by the way how its cleanest ?

Comment: Personally I don't think `entity_metadata_wrapper()` is cleaner than the `entity_extract_ids()` method. Plus you rely on the entity module being installed...

Comment: It's not necessarily cleaner, but it's a valid alternative, especially if you're using metadata wrappers anyway. Maybe @develkar or Junaid could edit their answer to include both of the alternatives ? (Junaid, maybe you could add links to the Entity module and to the page about entity_metadata_wrappers too?)

Comment: @AliceHeaton another alternative added.

Answer (score 3):

Try [entity_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_load/7)

> Load entities from the database.
>
> The entities are stored in a static memory cache, and will not require
> database access if loaded again during the same page request.

#### Parameters

**$entity_type**:
The entity type to load, e.g. node or user.

**$ids**:
An array of entity IDs, or FALSE to load all entities.

**$conditions**:
(deprecated) An associative array of conditions on the base table, where
the keys are the database fields and the values are the values those
fields must have. Instead, it is preferable to use EntityFieldQuery to
retrieve a list of entity IDs loadable by this function.

**$reset**:
Whether to reset the internal cache for the requested entity type.

#### Return value

An array of entity objects indexed by their ids. When no results are
found, an empty array is returned.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a very lightweight way, performance-wise, to get the node type from node id - you can use a single select query on the node table.

```
$type = db_query("SELECT type FROM {node} WHERE nid = :nid", 
                  array(':nid' => $nid))->fetchField();
```

That way, you don't need to invoke the entire entity hook system, with entity_load etc..

It's a single select query using the indexed node id.

Comment: we are not playing with only nodes here.

Comment: OP wrote "For example, if the type is 'node' and id is 7, I may get 'page' as bundle." hence the node based example answer.